How to add a concatenated column to the table in MySQL?
I want to take my existing columns First_Name and Last_Name and concatenate them to add a new column Full_Name to the table Employees. (I am working on MySQL Workbench.)
So, I tried concatenating columns of First_Name and Last_Name using the following query:
SELECT CONCAT(First_Name, " ", Last_Name) AS Full_Name FROM Employees;
But this is only for display purpose so if I wanted to add this column into the table, how do I do it??
This query is also for displaying purpose and doesn't actually include the new column into the table:
SELECT *, concat(First_name, " ", Last_name) AS Full_Name FROM Employees;

You can alter the table to add a new column called Full_Name. Then, update the table's new column to the concatenated value.

Use a view or a generated column. Don't add a real column, for then you would store the name redundantly and thus violate database normalization (2nd normalization form) that tells us not to have columns in a table that depend from each other. In your case you would always have to think about changing the other column when you changed one of the name columns. If you forgot this, you'd have data inconsistencies (two different names in the same row).

Make it a habit not to use double quotes for strings. Double quotes are meant to delimit names in SQL, not strings. Use single quotes instead: CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name). Or even better: CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name), because this only puts in the blank when necessary; in case first or last name is null, it will not add a blank.

first you need to add column with Full_Name  then update the Full_Name column
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD COLUMN Full_Name VARCHAR(100);

UPDATE Employees 
SET Full_Name = CONCAT(First_Name, " ", Last_Name);


This is exactly how not to do it. This violates database normalization (2NF), because the name columns depend on each other, which can lead to data inconsistencies. How to deal with a row that contains 'Sue', 'Miller', 'John Smith' for instance? Which name is correct, which is incorrect? Instead, we'd either create a view to generate the full name or a computed columns, as shown in prasad_'s answer.

Double quotes delimit names in SQL by the way. It is single quotes that are meant to limit string literals. While MySQL allows double quotes in this place, you should still not use them, and rather stick to the SQL standard.

This is another way of adding a new column with values derived from other columns. The following generates the concatenated Full_Name column value and stores it.
ALTER TABLE Employees 
  ADD COLUMN Full_Name VARCHAR(25) 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT_WS(" ", First_Name, Last_Name)) STORED;

INSERT INTO 
  Employees (First_Name, Last_Name)
    VALUES ("John", "Doe");

SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Full_Name FROM Employees;

+------------+-----------+-----------+
| First_Name | Last_Name | Full_Name |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| John       | Doe       | John Doe  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+

Note: The above ALTER TABLE also updates the Full_Name column values for the existing rows with the derived values.
Reference: MySQL 8 - ALTER TABLE and Generated Columns

This (or a view) is the way to go. I'd use CONCAT_WS here though, for the case that first_name or last_name can be null, and we would not want to add a blank then. And I don't think that it is necessary to make this computed column STORED, as we probably won't index it (as we can always index the first and last name instead).

@ThorstenKettner The computed column can be VIRTUAL (instead of STORED).

CREATE TABLE New_Employees (
EmployeeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name VARCHAR(255),
Last_Name VARCHAR(255),
Full_Name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO New_Employees (First_Name, Last_Name, Full_Name)
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, CONCAT(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name) AS Full_Name
FROM Employees;

This query creates a new table called New_Employees with columns EmployeeID, First_Name, Last_Name, and Full_Name. Then, it inserts data from the existing Employees table into the new table, with the Full_Name column being the concatenation of First_Name and Last_Name. Adjust the data types and lengths as needed for your specific requirements.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
